# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I went trough many similar topics like mine, but found no solution for my code.
First of all I simply want to run my webcam and see a picture.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
  re,img=cap.read()
  cv2.imshow("video output", img)
  k = cv2.waitKey(10)&0xFF
  if k==27:
     break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also tried it with:

```
if img is not None:
```

I still get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow
```

I have to say that I am not using my laptop webcam so its id is not 0, but it should be 1. I read about solutions like in c++: `frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
     if (frame.empty()) break;`
But how to do it in Python? I do not think that this will fix my problem?
Has anybody a solution?

Best regards

Comment: Your `frame` is empty. You can check first if `cap.isOpened()` , and then the `re` value from `cap.read()`

Comment: So you mean simply put `if cap.isOpened:` before cap.read()?

Comment: That before entering the loop to check if the capture is opened correctly. Then you need to check that each frame you grab is grabbed correctly

Comment: If I put `if cap.isOpened:` before the loop the code stops. So I have to create another loop for this right? Is there a good way? And how can I check if the frame is grabbed correctly?

Comment: Please read again my comments, and the OpenCV documentation. I already answered your questions

Comment: Oh ok I made a mistake, you said to also check for the re value if it is open. So first check i `cap.isOpened()`then enter the loop, an after `re = cap.read()`check if `re`is also opened. If it is opened then `cv2.imshow`, correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: you check `re` to see if the grab succeeded. But yes, correct

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for your patience, one last question. Now my code does not enter the loop. This means the cap is not opened. Should I simply create another loop or is there a better way?

Comment: Usually if cap is not opened you exit with an error... It's up to you to be sure that you can open it.

Comment: I am not sure what you're meaning. I check if it isOpened and I get false. Then I try to reopen it with `cap.open(1)`, still False. The camera works fine, I just tested it in OBS. And I do not get any errors, it simply does not enter the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [OpenCV docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html):

> cap.read() returns a bool (True/False). If frame is read correctly, it
>   will be True.
>
> ...
>
> Sometimes, cap may not have initialized the capture. In that case,
>   this code shows error. You can check whether it is initialized or not
>   by the method cap.isOpened(). If it is True, OK. Otherwise open it
>   using cap.open().

Thus your code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

device = 1
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
# if capture failed to open, try again
if not cap.isOpened():
    cap.open(device)

# only attempt to read if it is opened
if cap.isOpened:
    while True:
        re, img = cap.read()
        # Only display the image if it is not empty
        if re:
            cv2.imshow("video output", img)
        # if it is empty abort
        else:
            print "Error reading capture device"
            break
        k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print "Failed to open capture device"
```

If you still have errors try changing device to -1, 0 or 2. Otherwise, it may be an issue unrelated to OpenCV such as driver issues.